Why is docker.sock ownership not being preserved when bind mounted?
I've just upgraded Docker Desktop (on Windows 11) from version 4.27 to 4.29. Now when I run a container with /var/run/docker.sock bind mounted, the group ownership is being changed from root:docker to root:root inside the container.
$ docker run -it -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock docker:cli ls -l /var/run/docker.sock
srw-rw---- 1 root root 0 Apr 10 19:39 /var/run/docker.sock

What could be causing this? Is this a bug or is it by design? And if so, what is the correct way to bind mount docker.sock now?
One work around is to run chown root:docker /var/run/docker.sock inside the container on startup. Another is to re-install docker desktop 4.27. Neither is satisfactory.

Docker desktop on what host OS? Are rootless containers being used?

Docker Desktop on Windows. In general I use non-root users in the containers but I get the same issue when running as root (as per the example docker run).

If I run a docker:dind image without mounting anything at all docker.sock is root:root.

same issue with windows 11 as host and having Error response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "bind"  save with ver 2.48  with ver 2.47.2 all good

With v2.47, the docker.sock file on the host and in the container are the same as can be proved by checking the inode (ls -i /var/run/docker.sock). With v2.48, the files are not the same. The inodes are different which explains how the permissions can be different.

This is no longer an issue in the latest version of docker desktop (v4.31.1). I can only assume it was a bug that has since been fixed.
There's mention of a regression relating to /var/run/docker.sock from v4.28 being fixed in v4.30
https://docs.docker.com/desktop/release-notes/#4300
